# OPC UA : Get the current state of items on server

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

I am currently working on a OPC UA application to get data form a OPC server. I get data when an item has changed using MonitoredItems, but I would like to get the data from the server at any time, not only when the values change.

Does someone know how to do that ?

The code I am using comes from here : [OPC UA : minimal code that browses the root node of a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573689/opc-ua-minimal-code-that-browses-the-root-node-of-a-server)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can issue a ReadRequest for the values you're interested in at any time.