# OPC UA Browse with ReferenceDescription does not return full list of nodes

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

I am using the sample in the first answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573689/opc-ua-minimal-code-that-browses-the-root-node-of-a-server) for browsing the tree of nodes of a server, but I cannot receive all the nodes expected (Object nodes and Variables). The nodes that I expect belong to classes that I am not filtering out and I do not know what is happening. The only node I am getting is an "Icon" node, which is a Variable.

Moreover, it is important to say that this problem does not appear at the first level of the hierarchy; in the first few Browse calls I am able to get all nodes expected (i.e.: Object, Method, and Variable).

I know that this question may seem unclear, but I do not really know how to describe better my problem and unfortunately I cannot share the server and too much of the code.

Anybody has a clue of what is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could share a wireshark packet capture of the Browse Service ?

Comment: Try your code with the ProsysOpc simulation server. Its got a Request/Response log that's helpful.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I had to stop the development for a couple of days. Anyhow, I found out that the problem was with the "ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences" parameter in the Browse function of the example I linked above. Apparently, that parameter does not return nodes that have an "Organise" reference type. It was just this...